# Python error module object is not callable

Tags: python, module, whois

I have this code:

```
import whois
print whois.whois('google.com')
```

Run in IDLE:

[image]

But It run ok in console:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script file is itself called `whois.py`; Python is importing that instead of the library module. Call it something else.